# How to describe 3-dimentional array as tables?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I would like to consider what's called "dynamic programming". For example, the knapsack problem is often explained with the table, which represents 2-dimensional array. This helps my understanding.

But there are some problems require me to use 3-dimensional array to solve. Is there any good way to describe 3-dimensional array's value flow as table(s) ?

Comment: 2d array is like a rectangle n x m made of small squares 1x1. You can write anything inside one of the squares. 3d array is like a cuboid n x m x k made of 1x1x1 small cubes. Each small cube stores a value of you.

Comment: How about a 2D array where every element is an array in itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned 2d and 3d arrays in the context of dynamic programming, let me offer an example of a two-dimensional problem yielding itself well to dynamic programming-based approach, and then extend it into a third dimension. Perhaps it will help visualize it.

Let's consider this problem: you are given a matrix `A` with `n` rows and `m` columns filled with integer numbers, and you start in the cell of your choosing in the first row. Every turn, you move to the cell either directly below the one you're in, or to one of its neighbors. More formally, from cell `(i, j)` you can advance to one of `(i+1, j)`, `(i+1,j-1)`, `(i+1,j+1)`. Once you reach the final row, you sum up the numbers on all cells you have traversed. What is the maximum possible sum you can achieve this way?

The dynamic programming approach is as follows: introduce the second matrix `B` of the same dimensions as `A`, and define `B[i][j]` as "maximum possible sum achieved if you followed the conditions of the problem and reached cell `(i, j)`". In other words, if your journey started anywhere in the first row and ended in cell `(i, j)`, what could be the maximum sum?

This definition has a relatively simple recurrence relation:

```
B[0][j] = A[0][j]
B[i][j] = max(B[i-1][j], B[i-1][j-1], B[i-1][j+1]) + A[i][j] for i>0
```

Or in English: we came to `(i, j)` through one of `(i-1,j)`, `(i-1, j-1)`, `(i-1, j+1)`, hence we take the sum on the best of those paths and add value in `(i, j)` to it. So `B` is the DP table you referred to.

Now let's consider a similar problem in three dimensions: you are in a building with `K` floors, and each floor is a `n x m` matrix filled with integers. Let's call the matrix on floor `x` `A_x`, so for example the number in cell `(i, j)` on 3rd floor is `A_3[i][j]`. You start on any cell in the first floor, and every turn you can jump up one floor higher to either the cell directly above, or one of its 8 neighbors:

```
(i-1, j-1)  (i-1,  j )   (i-1, j+1)
( i,  j-1)  (  i,  j )   ( i,  j+1)
(i+1, j-1)  (i+1,  j )   (i+1, j+1)
```

Again, you finish when you get to the top floor, and you are trying to maximize the sum of all the cells you traversed.

Let's introduce a 3d matrix `B[k][i][j]` that will hold the maximum possible sum you could achieve if you started somewhere the first floor and currently reached floor `k`, cell `(i, j)`. The recurrence relation is:

```
B[1][i][j] = A_1[i][j]
B[k][i][j] = max(A_(k-1)[i-1][j-1], A_(k-1)[i-1][j], ..., A_(k-1)[i+1][j+1]) + A_k[i][j] for k>0
```

Those `...` in the formula stand for all the 8 directions (and now I really regret that I said 8, and shout at many if that made everything harder to understand).
So, in plain English, we are again saying something similar to before: we came to the cell `(i, j)` on the floor `k` from one of the 8 cells below `(i, j)` on floor `k-1`, so let's take the best path.

`B[k][i][j]` is the 3-dimensional matrix for holding DP entries, and it's essentially `k` tables stacked on top of one another.

Comment: I got the image of "k tables stacked on top of one another". Thank you. To visualize 3-dimensional array as tables means , so to speak I must write tables k times ( if I'm using dp[k][i][j]).